# Simultaneous collision for MD5 and SHA1?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-1, md5, attack

I know that both MD5 and SHA1 are considered cryptographically broken now that collisions can reasonably be computed. The question I have is: What is the likelihood that a collision could be found for data hat is hashed by each independently?

For instance, would it be reasonably be possible to do something such as …

```
[Hashed Doc] => [MD5]
[Hashed Doc] => [SHA1]

[Fake Doc] + [Padding] => [MD5]
[Fake Doc] + [Padding] => [SHA1]
```

where the adjusted padding for the fake document caused both signatures to remain the same?